# Deploy Vue Vite InertiaJS Laravel app on Vercel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, vercel, inertiajs

I made a website with `vue`, `InertiaJS` and `Laravel`, initially I want to host this website for free for testing purposes before i buy domain, so i deployed `MySql` on `aiven.io` and deployed `laravel` on `vercel` with the following `vercel.json` file:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "framework": null,
    "functions": {
        "api/index.php": { "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0" }
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.php"
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "production",
        "APP_DEBUG": "true",
        "APP_URL": "https://yourproductionurl.com",

        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",
        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie",



        // aiven MySql service

        "DB_CONNECTION": "mysql",
        "DB_HOST": "mysql-example.a.aivencloud.com",
        "DB_PORT": "some port",
        "DB_DATABASE": "some DB name",
        "DB_USERNAME": "some username",
        "DB_PASSWORD": "some password"
    }
}
```

Now when i open the deployed domain i get error : `Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Home/Index.vue. (View: /var/task/user/resources/views/app.blade.php)`.

`resources/js/Pages/Home/Index.vue` is the first page to show when the websites opens, which means that the server is not getting these files in `Pages` directory, i made sure to run `npm run build`, here is my `app.blade.php`:

`app.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Arabic:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        @routes
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body>
        @inertia

        <script>
            const locale = localStorage.getItem("locale");
                window.addEventListener("locale-changed", (event) => {
                    locale = event.detail.storage;
                });
            document.body.dir = locale === 'en' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl';
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontFamily =  locale === 'en' ? "Roboto" : "Noto Sans Arabic";

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "_vendor-SQfNrWup.js": {
        "file": "assets/vendor-SQfNrWup.js"
    },
    "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.eot": {
        "file": "assets/primeicons-5P3lgTyi.eot",
        "src": "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.eot"
    },
    "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.svg": {
        "file": "assets/primeicons-bmyWY2nz.svg",
        "src": "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.svg"
    },
    "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.ttf": {
        "file": "assets/primeicons-DQ1UBV8x.ttf",
        "src": "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.ttf"
    },
    "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.woff": {
        "file": "assets/primeicons-ghXmUeij.woff",
        "src": "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.woff"
    },
    "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.woff2": {
        "file": "assets/primeicons-7GdVu_me.woff2",
        "src": "node_modules/primeicons/fonts/primeicons.woff2"
    },
    "node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/fonts/Inter-italic.var.woff2": {
        "file": "assets/Inter-italic.var-4Q_raY2J.woff2",
        "src": "node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/fonts/Inter-italic.var.woff2"
    },
    "node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/fonts/Inter-roman.var.woff2": {
        "file": "assets/Inter-roman.var-vq-Vth46.woff2",
        "src": "node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/fonts/Inter-roman.var.woff2"
    },
    "resources/js/app.js": {
        "assets": [
            "assets/Inter-roman.var-vq-Vth46.woff2",
            "assets/Inter-italic.var-4Q_raY2J.woff2",
            "assets/primeicons-5P3lgTyi.eot",
            "assets/primeicons-7GdVu_me.woff2",
            "assets/primeicons-ghXmUeij.woff",
            "assets/primeicons-DQ1UBV8x.ttf",
            "assets/primeicons-bmyWY2nz.svg"
        ],
        "dynamicImports": [
            "resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Auth/ForgotPassword.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Auth/Login.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Auth/Register.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Auth/ResetPassword.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Auth/VerifyEmail.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Profile/Edit.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Profile/Partials/DeleteUserForm.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Profile/Partials/UpdatePasswordForm.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Profile/Partials/UpdateProfileInformationForm.vue",
            "resources/js/Pages/Home/Index.vue"
        ],
        "css": ["assets/app-7LbE6mUY.css"],
        "file": "assets/app-7-_4SnFd.js",
        "imports": ["_vendor-SQfNrWup.js"],
        "isEntry": true,
        "src": "resources/js/app.js"
    }
}
```